# R programming: How can I get residuals output in a variable or to act like a data frame?

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I have an object:

```
noise.lm
```

it's just a simple linear model with an X and Y.

when I type in

```
resid(noise.lm)
```

it produces the residuals like this:

```
         1           2           3           4           5           6 
-0.40501681 -1.16960373 -0.66636219 -0.41798296  1.37942381  0.84336242
```

I would like to access the residual values without the observation numbers, maybe by making a data frame like this

```
   residual
1  -0.40501681
2  -1.16960373
3  -0.66636219
.       .
.       .
.       .
```

Or is there an easier way to store just the residual value in a variable like:

```
residual_variable

-0.40501681, -1.16960373, -0.66636219, -0.41798296,  1.37942381,  0.84336242
```

An example of what I would like to do would be something like testing for autocorrelation

```
plot(length(residual_variable),residual_variable)
```

or when trying to check normality with a histogram...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Will this do what you want?

```
    x <- c(1,3,5,7,9,7,9,11)
    y <- c(6,9,15,20,15,20,25,30)
    z <- lm(y ~ x)

    zz <- as.data.frame(resid(z))
    zz


# added code for a plot

zzz <- seq(1:dim(zz)[1])
plot(zzz, zz[,]) 

# alternate code for a plot

plot(resid(z))
```

Comment: Got this:

    MyData$Resids <- residuals(noise.lm)
where MyData is your data used to create noise.lm